# OpenGL ES (iOS): Make a texture follow another texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es, matrix

So I have an NSObject that has a texture (GLKTextureInfo) and matrix (GLKMatrix4) that defines where the texture gets displayed. What I would like to do is be able to copy that matrix and modify it so that I can create another NSObject that follows the first one by "attaching onto the bottom left corner of the first texture(T1)".

[image]

How would I go about creating that second matrix? If I knew the width and height of each texture I can calculate where I need the second one to go, but I'm not sure how to (or if I can) get the dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GLKTextureInfo has height, width, and origin properties. I think what's more relevant to you, however, is the height of the polygon onto which your texture is drawn (unless your using a point to draw it?).

Comment: Yes that could be a way to do it, while considering the scale and aspect you give to the object. However, I just ended up converting the origin of T1 to object coordinates, getting the bottom left corner of T1 (x = -0.5, y =-0.5) and converting them back to world coordinates.